# How to clear django modules caching?

Tags: django

When running via local Apache+wsgi got something like:

```
ImportError at /link/to/new-app
No module named views
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module
  35. __import__(name) 
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/site/apps/new-app/urls.py in <module>
  2. import views
```

The views module does exist, you can import it in the python shell, and it runs OK in django dev web server. So I guess it's a caching issue.
Tried to restart Apache, remove all pyc files + touch all files (both in django dir and the code), and even restart the machine, nothing helps.

Django ver: 1.2.4

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your web server is out of file descriptors. Use `ulimit` to increase the number available before starting httpd.

Comment: Where and how do I use it? tried ulimit in shell (Ubuntu) got "unlimited" response, but the problem continues

Comment: In the script that runs httpd. See `help ulimit`.